# Doubt about the procedure of parametrization

Tags: parametrization

I can't understand how parametrics equations are found. For example, I realize that the parametrization of the curve given by the intersection of the plane $\ 2x+2y+z=2$ and $z=x^2+y^2$ is:

- $x=-1+\cos(t)$
- $y=-1+\sin(t)$
- $z=6-2\cos(t)-2\sin(t)$
- $0\leqslant t\leqslant2\pi$

Or that the surface of $x^2+y^2=2$ delimited by $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ is:

- $x=\sqrt2\cos(u)$
- $y=\sqrt2\sin(u)$
- $z=v$
- $0\leqslant u\leqslant\pi/2$ and $0\leqslant v\leqslant\sqrt2$

But what is the step by step to find those equations?

Comment: Are you sure you got these right? For the first problem $x^2+y^2=2-2x-2y\implies (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2=4$, which is inconsistent with your first two bullet points.

Comment: Now I see it.I got them from a list and didn't check. What would be a correct parametrization then?

Comment: You need to double the trigonometric functions' coefficients.